# Error adding a new classic portlet in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm trying to create a new classic portlet. When I create one though, it shows up with this text: "*There was an error while rendering the portlet*."

I've looked at several sites trying to figure out how to create a portlet, but am having trouble. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please tell us which Plone version you are using and is there more info in error-message or site-logs?

Comment: Plone 3.3.5
I realize that a static text portlet will work for what I need, and that one works fine.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Now it also rises to me of the dust of ancient times, that 'classic portlets' exist only for backward-compatibility reasons (abbreviated with "BBB" in the Plone-world), never needed to use them, though.